# Ember.js Query Parameters - Update query results when creating a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I am using the new query-params in Ember.js to filter entries by date. I have added a field to add new entries, with the date being automatically assigned as the query date. When a new entry is added it only shows up on the page when I refresh. Is there any way to retrigger the query without changing the query itself?

Controller: (simplified)

```
queryParams: 'date'
date: null

filteredEntries: ( ->
  date = @get('date')
  model = @get('model')
  if (date)
    return entries.filterProperty('date', date)
  else
    return entries
).property('date', 'model')

actions:
  createEntry: ->
    entry = @store.createRecord('entry', { date: @get('date') })
    entry.save()
```

I also tried this, but it didn't work:

```
entry.save().then -> this.transitionTo({queryParams: { date: @get('date')}})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for (in your route):

```
App.MyRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
        date: {
            refreshModel: true
        }
    },
});
```

This will refresh your model everytime the value of `date` changes.

Comment: The date isn't changing, I am adding and destroying entries within the current query scope.